# Taxonomy structure help

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have been struggling with Taxonomies and Post Types for a while and could really use help understanding what would be the best implementation for my situation.

Have a look here: http://shaulzofef.com/netivyah/resources/audio-lessons/

I setup a few post types; Books, Magazines, Articles and Audiolessons.
I setup a few Taxonomies: Language, Author, Teacher.
Teacher is associated to one post type only, Audiolessons, but Language is associated to all post types.
I made a submenu on the audio page that has English, Hebrew and Russian at parent level and underneath a list of teachers in each language.

I have a few problems:
1 - Some teachers teach in more than one language, so if I click on Joseph under English how will I make it list only the posts with taxonomy term Joseph AND taxonomy term English?
2 - When I click on English it lists the English Audiolessons AND other posts associated with taxonomy term English (articles, books and so on). How would I list only the Audiolessons?

I realize I can code a Wordpress query for posts related to post type and taxonomy, however that will require a file for each combination..

I could create separate taxonomies for each post type, 'Audio-Language' for instance, then I could easily list them, but that doesn't seem right.. then what if I do want an option to list all English resources together.
Should I create hierarchical taxonomies instead?.. 
I'm getting confused.
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Your page isn't loading. I don't know if this will help you, but I found it helpful when I had multiple taxonomies: http://thereforei.am/2011/10/28/advanced-taxonomy-queries-with-pretty-urls/

Comment: Thank you @helgatheviking. That indeed helped. Now audiolesson/language/english/teacher/josephshulam/ gives me what I want. but audiolesson/language/english still lists all english posts, including not audio lessons. It is not filtering by post type. What am I doing wrong? I would appreciate if you have a  look at my plugin file [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/677948/netivyah.php)

Comment: You can add code to your answer instead of linking off-site.

Comment: It's just a long piece of code, I didn't want to mess the page...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to look over your entire plugin. If you are posting your entire plugin the odds are that you aren't asking a specific enough question and that you aren't posting *just* the relevant code. I would try rephrasing your question.

Comment: You're right. Thank you meanwhile. As soon as I realise where my problem is I will probably have a more specific question.

Comment: Feel free to edit this question when you do. I *think* you want to limit a taxonomy archive to a single post type, but it isn't clear.

Comment: Exactly. What I'm struggling to understand is how I should combine taxonomy and post type filtering. Basically what I need is to be able to create a menu item that lists for instance: English ('language' taxonomy) Audio lessons (Post Type). And a sub menu that lists Joseph's ('teacher' taxonomy) English ('language' taxonomy) Audio lessons (Post type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter your audio lessons post archive you could borrow from the article I linked you to and add a custom rewrite rule:

```
function wpa_add_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    $new_rules = array(
        'audio-lessons/language/(.+)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=audio-lesson&language=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1)
    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'wpa_add_rewrite_rules' );
```

After re-saving your permalinks, something like `http://example.com/audio-lessons/language/english` would show all the English audio lessons.

However, I am not sure the URL you provided is a post type archive and not a custom page template.

If it is a page template and you are running multiple `Wp_Query()` calls you could register a new query variable and build your `tax_query` up from that.

```
function wpa_add_new_query_vars($vars) {   
    $vars[] = 'language'; // name of variable you want to add       
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpa_add_new_query_vars', 10, 1 );
```

You may not even need this part as I think the query var is registered when you register the taxonomy.

Then you could query posts like so:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'audio-lesson'
);

if( $lang = get_query_var( 'language' ) ){
    $args['tax_query'] = array( array( 
            'taxonomy' => 'language',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => '$lang'
        ));
}

$my_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I can't really test this and the `tax_query` can sometimes trip me up with its array of arrays so I'm not 100% sure it will work.

Then anywhere you wanted to make a link to a specific language section you could use [`add_query_arg()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg)

Comment: Thank you so much! Your custom rewrite rule worked!
And the reason I was getting audio lessons of all languages before was because I had a query_posts in my archive-audiolesson.php page that overwrote the query. My bad.
Thanks again :)

Comment: And to build the menu by URL's I used the [Relative Menu Item Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/relative-menu-item/)